# Can air in a Hotwater tank, prevent the pressure release valve from working?

Tags: valve

I know I should bleed the system of air, but will any air in the tank prevent the pressure release valve from opening?

I am installing a new hot water tank. I intend to fill it, and then bleed off any air, but am concerned that if the pressure is too high it will damage the tank before I can bleed it. I am trying not to have a open pipe  to prevent damage to the room. And therefore would prefer not to fill (until water overflows) then fit the valve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air in the tank won't prevent the valve from opening. But if an electric water heater it can cause damage to the element. Just don't turn the water heater on until it is plumbed in then open a hot water tap and turn the supply to the water heater on. When the tank is full the tap will quit spitting air and run normally. After this is done it is safe to turn the heat on.

Comment: I was not planning on wiring tne electrics in till after the water wax completed, to prevent any 'splliage' issues, but many thanks for the safety reminder